# YouTube video is blocked even with a verified app

Tags: google-api, youtube, insert, youtube-api, verification

Context: using `googleapis` (more specifically `youtube.videos.insert` method) to upload a video to YouTube. The video is successfully uploaded but it is private (locked). I'm aware about the verification and I already went through it. My app is verified.

[image]

However, I'm still getting this when I upload a video.

[image]

Any ideas?

I also just submitted this form https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form (waiting for a response)

Edit #1:
I got an answer from YouTube API Service Team that my API client is not compliant to this document https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service with a couple of suggestions how to fix the problems. I'll do today and will email them back. So, the bottom line is - we have to verify our app so we can publish and we have to be fill that form above to make our API client verified.

P.S.

this same question is also published here https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/111169095/video-uploaded-via-the-api-appears-as-private-locked-even-tho-my-app-is-verified?hl=en

Comment: How much time has passed since you sent the info via the linked form? - if you need further assistance, my suggestion is to send more details in a ticket via [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) - it might be a bug.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, I'll follow up with that issue tracker. There has been +10 hours since I posted the form.